Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS starts up slowly on Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 460
I decided to give Ubuntu another shot and installed it alongside an existing Windows installation following this guide on my machine.
Unfortunately, start-up is really slow and shutdown is not completed (GUI and terminal), while reboot works as expected, albeit slowly:
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.804s (firmware) + 10.797s (loader) + 27.367s (kernel) + 11.637s (userspace) = 56.608s 
graphical.target reached after 11.617s in userspace.

$ systemd-analyze blame
5.717s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
4.825s plymouth-quit-wait.service
2.193s NetworkManager.service
2.055s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1.948s snapd.seeded.service
1.721s fwupd-refresh.service
1.665s fwupd.service
1.309s snapd.service
1.057s apport.service
 731ms udisks2.service
 708ms dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
 680ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
 624ms rsyslog.service
 624ms power-profiles-daemon.service
 562ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
 529ms accounts-daemon.service
 515ms polkit.service
 513ms systemd-rfkill.service
 473ms secureboot-db.service
 460ms gpu-manager.service
 459ms e2scrub_reap.service
 424ms apparmor.service
 404ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 392ms systemd-resolved.service
 361ms user@1000.service


Can the Network Manager be configured to not hold up the startup process and maybe the plymouth-quit-wait.service? Thank you for your suggestion.

I think 11.617s is not really slow for graphical.target. What time would you expect?
